# R equivalent to pip install -e

Tags: r

When developing your own R package locally on your machine with devtools, is there is an editable install option? I.e. if you make a local package in python you can pip install with -e which means that if you then change the scripts of the package then it automatically updates your package rather than working with a frozen version since (I believe) it creates pointers to scripts rather than compiled copies. The alternative of removing and reinstalling the package each time is 20 seconds of my life I could do without after each change. I know I could source(rscript) but then I would lose the fact it is a package, for example package::function would no longer work.

Comment: It's not an exact equivalent, but `devtools::load_all()` simulates installing and reloading your package. You can make changes to your scripts, then call `devtools::load_all()` to reload all modifications into the currently-running R environment.

Comment: Do you know if under the hood devtools::loadall() modifies , or is it a more efficient re-install?

Comment: Here are [all the steps performed by load_all](https://devtools.r-lib.org/reference/load_all.html#details).